# e^-it as t approaches infinity

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I evaluate 
$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }  e^{-it}$$

I feel like it should be 0, but I'm not sure if the $i$ changes things.

Comment: $|e^{-it}|=1$..

Comment: Assuming that $t$ is real, the function $t \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{-it}$ is periodic, and does not have a limit at infinity.

Comment: Complex numbers can be represented in the form $re^{i\theta}$ where $r$ is a radius from the origin and $0\leq\theta<2\pi$ is the angle of rotation from the positive real axis. But this function is periodic in $\theta$; you're just traveling around the boundary of a circle as you increase $\theta$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$e^{iat}=\cos at + i \sin at$$

Answer (score 2):

$e^{it}=(-1)^{n}$ when $t=n\pi$ so the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can interpret this limit using argand plane. The solution region is a square and there is no definite value for this limit[image: argand plane limit of e^-it solution]